# Is there any way to get out of a dungeon once cleared?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It is very annoying having to walk all the way back out of the cave once I have done the mission, especially if there is lots of traps.

Comment: It's been a while since i played it but from what i remember, every single dungeon had a shortcut to the exit in the final room, though sometimes it was hidden behind something.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generally in most dungeons when you clear it (kill the boss, loot the final chest, get a word of power, etc.) there is a path you can keep exploring. The path can sometimes be activated by a switch or lever and opens up a new route. This new route can either take you near the entrance of the dungeon or takes you outside. This eliminates the need to walk all the way back to the entrance the way you came.

Comment: This is correct. I've always been somewhat ambivalent about it though... while it's a nice thing to have from a gameplay perspective, the idea that every single dungeon/fort/etc has a "back door" is rather immersion breaking.

Comment: @Reid I think it would be immersion breaking to spend 5 minutes walking back through an empty dungeon. At the very least it would be a waste of time that could otherwise be spent playing.